# parse json for uitableview cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ios6

I have an application using `UITableview` application. If I click the `UITableViewcell` that bring JSON data. I created a `UIViewController` to display the information on the line that was selected in the`UITableView`.  My requirement is if I click the `UITableview` cell the corresponding PDF File will be displayed in the simulator.  I developed the code also.  But the pdf file not be displayed on the simulator.  I am new to the programming. My doubt is how to download PDF Files using json parser.Plz give me any idea or send me any sample code.Thanks in advance
This is My PDF URLS:

[UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/UIViewController_Class.pdf)

[QLPreviewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/QLPreviewController_Class.pdf)

This is my sample code.

```
JSONPARSERPDFVIEWCONTROLLER .M

-(void)loadData

{

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
connect=  [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

// delegate methods in json
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connectiondidReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [_data setLength:0];
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse called");
}

//connection did receive data

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSMutableData *)data
{
    [_data appendData:data];
}

/ /connection did finish loading

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{
     NSError *jsonError = nil;
     id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_data options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];

    if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) 
    {
        //NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)jsonObject;
    }
    else if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {

        NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;  
        NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]init];
        array=[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@""];
        dataDictionary=[array objectAtIndex:0]; 
        NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionary);
    }
    [urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"UIViewController"]];
    NSLog(@"%@",urlsArray);
    //[self dataLoadingFinished:responseString withData:downloadData];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{        
    //[connection release];     
    // = nil;
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError called");
}
```

**uitableview.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    fileNameList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"UIViewController",@"QLPreview class",@"UIDocumentInteractionController", nil];    
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [fileNameList count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [fileNameList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    jsonparser *jParser=[[jsonparser alloc]init];

    jParser.selectedIndex=indexPath.row;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:jParser animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Include the code for tableview datasource and delegate

Comment: ya.i am include the code uitableview datasource and delegate.the view will be navigate the pdf view controller.But pdf will not be displayed

Comment: plz anybody help me how to display pdf file using above links

Comment: need some help we need code.This is not enough

Comment: i am updating my code.plz help me.my urls also mention above.thanks in advance.send me example or modify the above code

Comment: I don't see anything related to a PDF in your code above, just JSON. If the JSON works ok, remove it from the question and show the PDF part that doesn't work.